# using jquery ready() function on a js call

Tags: jquery

is there any way to add jquery ready() function to a code like this?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxxxxxxxxxx?id=35&amp;k=bf6ee6f24e058a864298&amp;method=div' id='block-4e058a8642973ae2c431f0d8'></script>
```

suppose we can't add ready function within the actual js code in that src link

if we can't, then is there anyway to make this script load last?

Comment: answers you are getting are all over the map because you haven't defined the issue with enough detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer you cant, without having the jquery library added.

but if you place the script just before the final `</html>` tag it should execute last.

Comment: let's say the embedded js contain output of html content, and we want it to display on a certain area of the page, so we can't put it before final </html>

Comment: but just because you need it to add to a certain spot doesnt mean it has to be in that spot. its the joys of the dom. have an empty div with an ID then use `document.getElementById(idOfEmptyDiv)` in the external script and then append the new html

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If you know jQuery will be loaded prior to this line  you can have the content contained in the following in the external file.

```
$(function () {
   // file content here
});
```

If you can't change the target file there are also script loading plugins that will allow control over when things are loaded.  This is easiest way.

For example yep/nope is popular. http://yepnopejs.com/

Comment: but we are not using the js content on our page, we're embedding it

Answer (score 0):

2 simple ways:

1. Put the script tag at the bottom of your page.
2. Create it dynamically with JS and add it to the page after your other scripts using something like:

Example:

```
window.onload = function() {
     var s = document.createElement('script');
     s.src = "http://yourscripthere";
     document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: in the second case, how do we add 'id' to the script

Comment: in this case, the id is id='block-4e058a8642973ae2c431f0d8'

Comment: s.id = 'block-4e058a8642973ae2c431f0d8'

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression it's because you want to change something in the src

```
$(function(){
    var your_id=35;
    $.getScript('http://xxxxxxxxxxx?id=' + your_id + '&amp;k=bf6ee6f24e058a864298&amp;method=div');
});
```

or if you want it to load after everything else has loaded

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var your_id=35;
    $.getScript('http://xxxxxxxxxxx?id=' + your_id + '&amp;k=bf6ee6f24e058a864298&amp;method=div');
});
```

Comment: im not trying to change something in the src, window.onload seems to be  a good way, but i want to pass the id, in this case is id='block-4e058a8642973ae2c431f0d8' for all css properties

Comment: what you're asking doesn't make sense i'm afraid